# Javascript compare 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays;

```
var partnerStatus = [];
var partnerStatusToCheck = ["VAL1","VAL2", "VAL3", "VAL4", "VAL5"];
```

Now the first array can have multiple values (some within, some not in partnerStatusToCheck)..It is dynamic..

My question is I want to check if `partnerStatus` has any value which is `not` in (i.e. outside of) `partnerStatusToCheck` and set a boolean flag for that.

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think the title "Javascript compare 2 arrays" matches the description or your comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to find if any of the values in `partnerStatus` is not found in `partnerStatusToCheck`, then you can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like this

```
console.log(partnerStatus.some(function(currentStatus) {
    return partnerStatusToCheck.indexOf(currentStatus) === -1;
}));
# false
```

If you are looking for a way to find if all the values in `partnerStatus` is found in `partnerStatusToCheck`, then you can use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) like this

```
console.log(partnerStatus.every(function(currentStatus) {
    return partnerStatusToCheck.indexOf(currentStatus) !== -1;
}));
# true
```

Comment: @testndtv It is still not clear. You might want to explain with an example and the expected output.

Comment: so i want a single boolean flag which should tell me if any of the values from partnerStatus is not in partnerStatusToCheck

Comment: @testndtv That is exactly what this code does. You just have to assign the return value of this function to a variable and that will have the boolean value you expect.

Comment: so for example if partnerStatus has one of the values containing say VAL2, the boolean flag (isValueinpartnerStatusToCheck) should return me  true ....if none of the values in partnerStatus are there in partnerStatusToCheck , the the boolean flag (isValueinpartnerStatusToCheck) should return me  false

Comment: Hmm...i thought since this would run in a loop, it would not return a single value....

Comment: @testndtv Please re-read the actual question you posted and the last comment you posted. They entirely contradict each other.

Comment: @testndtv Please check my answer now. I have no clue what you are asking. So, I included answers to all the possible interpretations of your question.